# Exception - unrecognized selector sent to instance was thrown while invoking

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

Does anybody know what this exception means and how to fix it?

`Exception - unrecognized selector sent to instance was thrown while invoking addNetworkingHandler on target BlobMdule with params ()`

[image: screenshot]

It appeared after I added React to the Podfile because of the new version of react-native-firebase. Do I have to 'unlink' React from the XCode Project first, add React to the Podfile and then run `pod install`? I dont find any tutorial or doc on the web that gives advice on how to solve the problem.

Thanks for help :D

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'DasHGR' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DasHGR

  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    # the following ones are the ones taken from "Libraries" in Xcode:
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  target 'DasHGRTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
  # pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.9.0'

  # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
  # It removes React from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
   post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == "React"
              target.remove_from_project
          end
      end
  end

end

target 'DasHGR-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DasHGR-tvOS

  target 'DasHGR-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: How did you fix this? I am running through the same issue after adding firebase to podfile.

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien see my response https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316600/6489268 interested if it helps ...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to @Kubwimana Adrien comment

Actually I don't know anymore what I did exactly but now my Pofile looks like this:

I added `yoga` to the targets that should be ignored on build time ... hope it helps

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'DasHGR' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DasHGR
  # Add new pods below this line

  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    # the following ones are the ones taken from "Libraries" in Xcode:
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    # 'RCTBlob',
    # 'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    # 'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    # 'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    # 'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'MerryPhotoViewer', path: '../node_modules/@merryjs/photo-viewer'

  # target 'DasHGRTests' do
    # inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  # end

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.9.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.9.0'

  # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
  # It removes React from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

          targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga RNFS) # <---- added yoga (and also RNFS)

          if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
              target.remove_from_project
          end
      end
  end

end

target 'DasHGR-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DasHGR-tvOS

  target 'DasHGR-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Your podfile looks more like mine.I have tried everything but no luck. I keep getting these errors. If you know about them please help. thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MhG5.png  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/tILKE.png

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien have you tried deleting Pods folder and node_modules folder, reinstalling Pods and modules and cleaning Xcode cache? It looks like Native Modules Form React Native itself are not loading correctly. I have also changed the order of the list of linked binaries with libraries in Xcode I think so that the RNFirebase lib is at the bottom of the list and all React Native libs are at the top

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien here is the current list: [https://i.imgur.com/o1DLCit.png](https://i.imgur.com/o1DLCit.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix the issue. All I did was to link RCTNetwork manually.